# Registered Stream Socket Transports - How can I add tls

Tags: php, apache

My PHP information currently says

```
Registered Stream Socket Transports : tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
```

I need the following set for my emailing software but I can't figure out what I need to do to install.

```
tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
```

OS CentOS 6, cPanel

Comment: Please elaborate on the environment. Your own server? Linux/Windows? Version? How was php installed? ...

Comment: It's CentOS with cPanel

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to upgrade to CentOS 7. When the php_openssl extension is compiled it checks for the openssl version. If it's >= 0x10001001L the extension registers the tls1.1 and 1.2 stream. At least the extension shipping with php 5.6 does. But since not even the tls1.0 stream shows up in your phpinfo() output probably your php version is also too old . If you can't upgrade you'd have to look for a newer version of openssl (incl the dev headers and libs) and a newer php version (and its extension) - whether that's less intrusive than an upgrade is up to you...